# Binding a trait to an object with Scala Guice

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, guice

This was going to be a question about how to get the binding to work, but in cleaning up my example ready to post I've actually managed to get it working - the problem is I have no idea why this works:

```
import org.specs2.mutable._
import com.google.inject.{ Inject, Module, Binder, Guice }
import net.codingwell.scalaguice.ScalaModule

object InjectorSpec extends Specification {
  val injector = Guice.createInjector(new ScalaModule() {
    def configure() {
      bind[Message].toInstance(MessageImpl)
      bind[MessageService.type].toInstance(MessageService) // This line makes it work?
    }
  })

  trait Message {
    val body: String
  }

  object MessageImpl extends Message {
    val body: String = "Hello!"
  }

  object MessageService {
    @Inject
    val message: Message = null

    def get = message.body
  }

  "MessageService" should {
    "Inject Message Implementation" in {
      MessageService.get mustEqual "Hello!"
    }
  }
}
```

Initially I was just binding the type to be injected (inject MessageImpl for Message). Somewhere along the way I picked up the second bind which is for the service, that isn't injected (so I don't understand the bind being required). Can anyone explain what's happening here and if this is the correct way to proceed?

Comment: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/A5HdRB-CIAAM3Ri.png:large *scnr*

Comment: @StefanKunze exactly! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the thing is that guice won't search through your program and find all the `@Inject` points that are in any class that you load anywhere. Instead, it needs to be given some path to find objects that you want it to inject stuff into. Generally, this is taken care of by the way you use Guice, since the standard pattern is:

```
val injector = Guice.createInjector(/* stuff */)
val main = injector.getInstance(classOf[Main])
main.mainMethod()
```

Guice performs injection on the instance of `Main` that you ask it to make/get, and recursively performs injection on all the things `@Inject`ed into `main`.

In your case, one of these statements would also have worked; I say "one of", because though I could tell you exactly how to inject into java I'm not entirely clear on how the scala compiler compiles scala companion objects into java classes. (that is, I don't know if `message` ends up being at the java level a static variable on the class called `MessageService$` or an instance variable, with `MessageService$` being instantiated only once through some threadsafe singleton pattern)

```
requestInjection(MessageService)
requestStaticInjection(MessageService.type)
```

The reason the `toInstance` statement worked is that Guice automatically performs injection on all onjects passed to `toInstance` as the injector is created. (something bound `.asEagerSingleton` will also have injection performed on it as the injector is coming up, as will all things bound as singletons if you create a "production mode" injector)

Comment: Aha, I thought it would be something along those lines. The use of @Inject and requestInjection seems cleaner to me over referring to the injector directly across my code base though?

Comment: Well, ideally you refer to `injector` only once, to call `getInstance` only once for your main class, and then everything gets injected from there out.

Scala companion objects screw things up a bit though because they are from the java point of view these singleton objects that were created outside Guice. Now, that's fine, but the trouble comes when you have these objects Guice didn't create that you want Guice to inject stuff into. I'm not up on scala-guice style (all my Guice experience is in java), but I think the solution is to never `@Inject` into companion objects.

Comment: That is, if you need singleton objects that you `@Inject` into, make them `trait`s or `class`es and bind them `.in(classOf[Singleton])` inside Guice; don't use companion objects for places where you need something injected.